# How can i do a for loop with 2 variables with the same range?

Tags: python

```
i = xCoordinate
s = yCoordinate
for i, s in range(5):
        pyautogui.moveTo(i, s)
```

Error:

```
for i, s in range(5):
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

Answer (score 9):

Why not use the same value twice?

```
for i in range(5):
    pyautogui.moveTo(i, i)
```

This should work fine. In any case, you could use `zip` to iterate over 2 different `range` objects:

```
for i, s in zip(range(5), range(5)):
    pyautogui.moveTo(i, s)
```

Oh and just a heads up, these lines:

```
i = xCoordinate
s = yCoordinate
```

Do absolutely nothing if you immediately after them reset the values of `i` and `s`

Comment: Isn't your first example the same as the second? i and s have the same value every time.

Comment: @Frank it is, but that's only because the ranges are the same, in principle they can be different

Comment: i think the point he's trying to make is that you can iterate through two ranges using the zip in-built

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if that is what you mean, but I'll try.
What you might need is:

```py
for i in range(5):
  for s in range(5):
        pyautogui.moveTo(i, s)
```

This will go through any possible combination of `i` and `s`.

Answer (score 2):

range() returns a single value. You cannot unpack it to two values.

Please take notice that your (disfunctional) code

```py
i = xCoordinate
s = yCoordinate
for i, s in range(5):
    pyautogui.moveTo(i, s)
```

would be equal to

```py
i = xCoordinate
s = yCoordinate
for i in range(5):
    pyautogui.moveTo(i, i)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could still create an initial variable which will serve as iterator and then assign its value at each iteration to two freshly created local variables

```
for i in range(10):#i is our iterator
#we assign i to both var1 and var2
  var1=i
  var2=i

  print(var1, var2) #we do whatever we want to do with the two variables
```